# Symfony form - reorder / sort CollectionType elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, symfony, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working with Symfony 2.7 to create a ToDo list. The `Form` contains a simple text field for the lists name and a collection of `items`:

```
class TodoType extends AbstractType {
    public function getName() {
        return 'todo_list';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\TodoList',
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Name',
                ...
            ))
            ->add('create', 'submit', array(
                'label' => 'Save',
                ...
            ));

            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $todoList = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $form
                    ->add('items', 'collection', array(
                        'type' => 'todo_list_item_type',
                        'allow_add'    => true,
                        'allow_delete' => true,
                        //'by_reference' => false,
                        'data' => ($todoList != null ? $todoList->getItems() : null),
                    ));

            });
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine. The items array is included in the form using an "array style" name:

```
<form ...>
    ...
    <ul class="sortable">
       <li>
            <input id="todo_list_items_0_name" class="item-name form-control" type="text" value="Shopping" placeholder="Name" required="required" name="todo_list[items][0][name]">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="todo_list_items_1_name" class="item-name form-control" type="text" value="Wash car" placeholder="Name" required="required" name="todo_list[items][1][name]">
        </li>
        ...
    <ul>
```

Now I would like to use the [jQuery Sortable Plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) to reorder the items. This works fine. The user the can reorder the items as he likes. However this does not have any influence on the order in which the items are stored.

**I think the problem is obvious:** The sortable plugin only changes the position of the items within the `DOM` while the items name, which include their array-index, stays the same. Thus Item0 still has `index = 0` when the form submitted, no matter of its new position within the list.

**Is there any build in solution to solve this?** The only solution I found sofar, is to listen to the `stop` event of the sortable plugin (triggered once reorder is complete) and to manually find/replace the index number within the field names using some JavaScript. This would work of course, but would be quite vulnerable to changes of the field names. If for example a future Version of Symfony would use `some_field_name_0` instead of `some_field_0_name`, the replacing code would not work any more.

Another solution would be, to extend the `Item` class with an additional field `sortOrder` and include this information as hidden field in the form. I would still have to update this index manually using JS but at least I would have more control over the format.

**However I wonder if there isn't an easier way. Sorting collection types is nothing special. So maybe there is an out of the box solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks reasonnable to me (though I will discuss further another option). There's no out-of-the-box solution, collection form type rely on data "natural" order.

The solution to your last problem is to use the "prototype" option. In your Twig view, you can display the prototype, meaning the HTML of any (new) form in your collection.
This is done automatically if you use `form_widget` or `form_row`, otherwise you can do this (from the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)):

```
<ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
    ...
</ul>
```

Then you can easily and reliably get the form name:

```
// Get the data-prototype explained earlier
var prototype = $('.tags').data('prototype');

// I assume we use jQuery
var $prototype = $(prototype);

// Get the item name
// by convention, instad of a numeric index it will contain __name__
var itemName = $prototype.attr('name');

// We can replace '__name__' it to whatever you like
var nameFor1 = itemName.replace(/__name__/g, 1);
```

**Another approach**

Another approach would be to add a `position` field to the `todo_list_item` element. Assuming it is a Doctrine entity, you can use the Sortable Doctrine extension on it: you wil find all details [here](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sortable.md) in the documentation, though you don't need to manually enable the Doctrine extension by yourself, you can use [StofDoctrineExtensionBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle).

In case it is a simple array of data (or you don ot want to add the extension, or save the position to the database), you can juste re-order the items from within the `setItems` method.

Comment: Thank you! Replacing `__name__` with some custom content that can easily be identified when re-setting the index numbers is a good option.  I already use the prototype to dynamically add new items to the form an I can easily change the `__name__` value in this step. However I do not understand how this works for items that already exist and are therefore loaded with the form. I do not have any influence on these values/items.

Comment: Taking the solution you found, re-naming fields so the correct order is "sent" to Symfony, it gives you a template to generate new names. Thus making your solution immune to Symfony upgrade/changes as you mention.